# Why is my HTML-Page refreshed everytime the user removes the uploaded image preview?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that uploads a preview of an image. As soon as an image other than the default is uploaded, a delete button appears as well. And when I click on this button to remove the image preview, the page is refreshed, which results in all the user input being removed. I don't know what is going wrong or where to look for. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="row fileinput-control">
  <img id="preview"  
       src="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png" width="500px" height="360px" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="addDeleteBttn()"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="file" id="image" style="display: none;" />
  <!--<input type="hidden" style="display: none" value="0" name="remove"remove">-->


  <a href="javascript:changeProfile()">
    <div class="file-btns">
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file" id="bildChoose">
        <i title="Bild auswählen" class="fa fileinput-new fa-file-image-o"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>        
  <a id="removeBttnFrame" href="javascript:removeImage()"></a>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <textarea class="form-control copyright" 
              placeholder="Geben Sie hier die Bildquelle an: Foto­graf, Lizenz, ...
    Ohne Quellen­an­ga­ben kann das Bild nicht angezeigt werden."
              name="offer[photo_copyright]" 
              id="offer_photo_copyright"></textarea>
    <div class="fileinput-description"></div>
  </div>
</div>


function changeProfile() {
  $('#image').click();
}

$('#image').change(function () {
  var imgPath = this.value;
  var ext = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
  if (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg") {
    readURL(this);
  } else {
    alert("Please select image file (jpg, jpeg, png).")
  }
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
      // $("#remove").val(0);
    };
  }
}

function removeImage() {
  $('#preview').attr('src', 'noimage.jpg');
  // $("#remove").val(1);
  $('#preview').attr('src', 'Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png');
}

function    addDeleteBttn() {
    var removeBttn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    removeBttn.title="Entfernen";
    removeBttn.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'

    removeBttn.className="removeBttnClass";

    document.getElementById("removeBttnFrame").appendChild(removeBttn);
}
```

Comment: share the code of addDeleteBttn function @armel

Comment: Your code is not refreshing the page when I removed the image

Comment: hmmm... weird.I've tried it in all browsers now ,just to make sure. The page is being refreshed in all of them...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your below code. I am not getting any errors. The page is not refreshing. Let me know if you are searching for something else. I have just renamed the button to Remove X because the awesome fonts were not included here.
I have also changed some code of yours because on every image preview, remove buttons were getting increasing.

```
 <div class="row fileinput-control">
       <img id="preview"  
          src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68333505,width-643,imgsize-204154,resizemode-4/googlechrome.jpg" width="500px" height="360px" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="addDeleteBttn()"/>
       <br/>
       <input type="file" id="image" style="display: block;" />
       <!--<input type="hidden" style="display: none" value="0" name="remove"remove">-->
       <a href="javascript:changeProfile()">
          <div class="file-btns">
             <span class="btn btn-default btn-file" id="bildChoose">
             <i title="Bild auswählen" class="fa fileinput-new fa-file-image-o"></i>
             </span>
          </div>
       </a>
       <a id="removeBttnFrame" href="javascript:removeImage()"></a>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <textarea class="form-control copyright" 
             placeholder="Geben Sie hier die Bildquelle an: Foto­graf, Lizenz, ...
             Ohne Quellen­an­ga­ben kann das Bild nicht angezeigt werden."
             name="offer[photo_copyright]" 
             id="offer_photo_copyright"></textarea>
          <div class="fileinput-description"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       function changeProfile() {
    $('#image').click();
}

$('#image').change(function () {
    var imgPath = this.value;
    var ext = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg") {
        readURL(this);
    } else {
        alert("Please select image file (jpg, jpeg, png).")
    }
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            // $("#remove").val(0);
            $('.removeBttnClass').remove();
            addDeleteBttn();
        };
    }
}

function removeImage() {
    $('#preview').attr('src', 'noimage.jpg');
    // $("#remove").val(1);
    $('#preview').attr('src', 'https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68333505,width-643,imgsize-204154,resizemode-4/googlechrome.jpg');
    $('.removeBttnClass').remove();
}

function addDeleteBttn() {
    var removeBttn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    removeBttn.title = "Entfernen";
    removeBttn.innerHTML = 'Remove X'
    removeBttn.className = "removeBttnClass";
    document.getElementById("removeBttnFrame").appendChild(removeBttn);

}
    </script>
```